# Remplazando el caracter "\" en js

Tags: replace

Tengo un problema en js, cuando intento reemplazar el carácter `"\"`, lo uso así:
`character.replace(/\/g, '');` o como: `character.replace("\", '');` o como: `character.replace('\', "");` y no funciona, me da error... creo que es porque me sale, pero quiero quitarlo de un enlace que tengo. ¿Como puedo quitarlo?

Tengo este enlace que el navegador no reconoce porque tiene el carácter `"\"`, así que quiero eliminarlo o darle un formato correcto al enlace:

```
 https:\/\/cdn.pixabay.com\/foto\/2022\/11\/24\/02\/28\/nubes-7613361_960_720.png
```

posdata: si elimina `"\"` el enlace funciona correctamente. (es lo que necesito :D)

¿Cómo puedo limpiar la URL? o ¿Cómo puedo eliminar `"\"` de la url?

Comment: Estas en SO en español. Las preguntas en otros idiomas son cerradas si no se traducen.

Comment: Duplicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/571413/remplazando-el-caracter-en-js