# Remplazando el caracter \ en js

Tags: javascript, replace

Tengo un problema en js, cuando intento reemplazar el carácter `"\"`, lo uso así: `character.replace(/\/g, '');` o como: `character.replace("\", '');` o como: `character.replace('\', "");` y no funciona, me da error... creo saber por que me sale. Pero quiero quitarlo de un enlace que tengo. ¿Como puedo quitarlo?

Tengo este enlace que el navegador no reconoce porque tiene el carácter `"\"`, así que quiero eliminarlo o darle un formato correcto al enlace:

```
https:\/\/cdn.pixabay.com\/foto\/2022\/11\/24\/02\/28\/nubes-7613361_960_720.png
```

posdata: si elimina `"\"` el enlace funciona correctamente. (es lo que necesito :D)

¿Cómo puedo limpiar la URL? o ¿Cómo puedo eliminar `"\"` de la url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que escapar del caracter **`\`** encerrándolo entre comillas dobles:

```js
function modificarURL(url) {
    let nuevaURL = url.replace('"\"', '');
    return nuevaURL;
}

console.log(modificarURL('https:\/\/cdn.pixabay.com\/foto\/2022\/11\/24\/02\/28\/nubes-7613361_960_720.png'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con :

```
character.replace("\\")
```

de este modo estás escapando el caracter `\` correctamente.

Ejemplo:

```js
let character = "https:\/\/cdn.pixabay.com\/foto\/2022\/11\/24\/02\/28\/nubes-7613361_960_720.png"
console.log(character.replace("\\"))
```